# Assisted Factory with two or more implementations of the same interface from one factory

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, dagger-2, dagger

I'm looking into implementation with Dagger of AssistedFactory that can create two or more implementations of the same interface.

I could find an [example](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html#:%7E:text=To%20return%20two%20different%20implementations%20for%20the%20same%20interface%20from%20your%20factory%2C%20use%20binding%20annotations%20on%20your%20return%20types%3A) with Guice in the docs.

What is the equivalent implementation using Dagger?

Thanks.

Comment: Could find a solution -
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2825 for anyone looking in the future.